# How to determine where particular style comes from using Chrome DevTools

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

If I inspect an element on a webpage and in the "Metrics" tab I see there are 10px margins on both side. How can I tell where these margins come from? Do they come from the default element style or specific css file (and on which line, they have been defined)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look at the Computed Style section on the top right.

It will show you every CSS property applied to the element, with an arrow that shows how each one was applied.

Comment: what if the source (eg main.css) is blank? i have some 3rd party scripts in my page which may be adding some styles, but i can't tell which script might be doing this. also, in the main Styles panel, i see the css files listed for each block of styles, but the top block has no file name shown. any ideas?